# How to pass a value from C# to SSIS package?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, parameters, ssis

I have this source table

```
    Employee(ID, Name)
```

I have this Destination Table

```
    EmployeeImported(ID,Name,DesgnationID)
```

During transformation I want to Insert DesignationID from C#. I add a parameter in dataflowtask. Now I don't know what to write in script task. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need  a script component to do that, you can use derived column:
[image]

you just need to create a column inside the derive column component and assign the parameter to it.
Then the new column will be available on the pipeline and you can map it to the destination as any other source field.